# What's the meaning of foreignKey in Sequelize.hasMany/belongsTo?

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js, rdbms

I was recently using Sequelize the ORM.

I have two tables. One is `Users` and the other is `Posts`

The schema of these two tables are as follows

```
Users {
  id: Integer,
  name: String,
  age: Integer
}

Posts {
  id: Integer,  // refers to the id of post itself
  author_id: Integer, // refers to the id of the author of this post
  title: String,
  content: String
}
```

I want to create an one(Users)-to-many(Posts) association between them. In order to do that, I need to specify the **hasMany** & **belongsTo** in the models.

However, I am very confused about the meaning of the parameters foreignKey / sourceKey / targetKey.

Say that I already define and create my table with migrations. The name of the attribute which is the foreignKey is **author_id** in this case.

My guess is, in `belongsTo`, `foreignKey` means "the name of the attribute that is going to be foreignKey in the source table"?

But in `hasMany`, `foreignKey` means "the name of the attribute that is referenced by the coming foreignKey"

So, `foreignKey` in `belongsTo` will be **author_id** (in table Posts) but `foreignKey` in `hasMany` will be **id** (in table Users) ?

Furthermore, what on earth do the sourceKey/targetKey mean!?

Answer (score 0):

Well... you have an interesting case above... if you used user_id instead of author_id then you might get away without declaring these as sequelize might assume them correctly... However because you named it author_id then your hasMany definitely needs to know that the foreign key is named author_id in your post table... Let's say that you named your id in the user table something like "user" instead of "id".... well sequelize won't understand that and be able to infer what it is joining on, so you would say the the sourceKey = "user" and foreignKey = "author_id"... To further that one more you may run into issues in database design where you need to specify what the targetKey or otherKey is because someone was naming things whacky... so like you said above in your belongsTo author_id would have no clue that it was supposed to map back to "user" for it's join, so you would specify foreignKey = "author_id" and otherKey = "user"...  This stuff took me a while to wrap my head around as well because i did not get to design the database i implements graphql/sequelize against... Therefore i had to make wide use of sourceKey, targetKey, and otherKey etc etc in my joins..

Try and think of it really logically and it will make more sense... if your primary key is always "id" and your foreignKey is always "tablename_id" then you won't need to worry too much about the other properties.. but when naming doesn't line up, sequelize needs to be told what keys to use, and that is why those other properties exist.. Sequelize is damn smart, but it can't make up for poor db design or bad join column naming... Hope this helps, if not i have plenty of examples i can post for you.. Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. However, I am still confused about one thing. I saw a lot of examples use the same foreignKey name for both hasMany and belongsTo. But I saw the documentation said the foreignKey in hasMany is the name of the foreign key attribute in the "target table", and the  foreignKey in belongsTo is the name of the foreign key attribute in the "source table".
Shouldn't they be different since they have different name in different tables(e.g. id for Users table and user_id for Posts table)?

Comment: That is correct, yes... hasMany foreign key would be user_id if that existed, but you made it author_id.... you may have to set sourceKey to author_id and foreignKey to if in your belongsTo